# Why does NamedTemporaryFile().write (without intermediate variable) result in "I/O operation on closed file"?

Tags: python, destroy, temporary-files

I have the following script, which does the same thing twice, in very slightly different ways. The first works, the second does not:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tempfile

fhandle=tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".",delete=False)
fhandle.write("hello")

tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".",delete=False).write("hello")
```

I get the follow error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 7, in <module>
     tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile().write("hello")
 ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

In my example script, I have put them together to show that the first one works. This does not affect the results, just points out that there is a difference.

Is this a bug in Python? Something weird about my machine? Expected behaviour? Correct behaviour? It looks like the object is being destroyed before the write().

Python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

Comment: Something is not as it appears in the implementation of `NamedTemporaryFile`. Why would you want do this?

Comment: The only thing I can deduce is that `__del__` somehow  gets called on the result of `NamedTemporaryFile` before the call to `write` occurs. Why that would happen, I do not know.

Comment: Looks like garbage collection - no references to the temp file instance and it become closed immediately.

Comment: No errors for me with Python 2.7.5 on a Windows machine... Note the docs say the returned object is a _file-like_ object, so maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: @martineau It is of type tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper. It's definitely file-like.

Comment: @alecxe: It's still being referenced within the expression being evaluated.

Comment: @martineau yeah, probably the behavior is platform-dependent.

Comment: My example is a gross over-simplification of the original script. For the actual code, I include the delete=False parameter. The files are then left there for another process (sms-tools, q.v.) to find and process. I didn't think that the file not being deleted was relavent to the question.

Comment: added (dir=".",delete=False) to the code, so the files aren't deleted.

Comment: @AMADANONInc.: Since (obviously) you're able to reproduce the problem and the `tempfile` module is written in Python, perhaps you could try running your simple test case under the Python debugger [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) and observe exactly what happens. You can do this by putting a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` right before the `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".",delete=False).write("hello")` line and then stepping through the code using multiple `s(tep)` commands.

Answer (score 2):

Correct answer (from both answers to this question, and further test): This is a bug.

I have raised a bug, which can be seen here: http://bugs.python.org/issue18879

Answer (score 0):

I think the comments from @Eric Urban and @alecxe are right, the file is closed - depending on the platform - based on the refcount, or something similar. I tried looking at a newly created tempfile object using a similar process:

```
>>> tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile().__dict__
{'close_called': True, 'name': '/tmp/tmpCRzR_c', 'file': <closed file '<fdopen>', mode 'w+b' at 0x7f9448e541e0>, 'delete': True}

>>> a = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
>>> a.__dict__
{'close_called': False, 'name': '/tmp/tmpnmWpQ5', 'file': <open file '<fdopen>', mode 'w+b' at 0x7f9448e54270>, 'delete': True}
```

So some time after creation, `close` is being called on your newly created temp file, probably as there are no references to it. Depending on your platform and the way you call it, closing a file may also delete it.

Comment: From the source of [`tempfile.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/18a3528f661d/Lib/tempfile.py#l427) you can definitely see what it does wrt to closing the file is os-dependent.

Comment: Actually I think I see a bug [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/18a3528f661d/Lib/tempfile.py#l379) in `tempfile.py`, where from the comments above it I think it should be `self.unlink = _os.unlink`. Can't test whether that's the cause of the OP's problem myself, since I'm on Windows...

Comment: In `_TemporaryFileWrapper`, line 379? You could well be right there. I'm not sure whether `__del__` or `close` should be called (something is calling one of those) in the OP's situation, though.

Comment: I can confirm that __del__ ("Called when the instance is about to be destroyed") is being called BEFORE the exception. Why is it being destroyed when there are still method calls pending?